# How to start streaming latest lines from an ongoing written .txt file in C#?

Tags: c#, file, timer, filereader, streamreader

I want to start streaming lastest lines from an ongoing written `.txt` file. Each line should be read every 128 milliseconds.

The code I use is always looking at the file from the first line. First I initialize the `StreamReader`s and the `timer`. Here is the code:

```
public void StartTimer()
{
    FileStream fileStream = File.Open(_fileWl1, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
    StreamReaderWl1 = new StreamReader(fileStream);
    FileStream fileStream2 = File.Open(_fileWl2, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
    StreamReaderWl2 = new StreamReader(fileStream2);

    _realTimeSimulationTimer.Interval = 128;
    _realTimeSimulationTimer.Elapsed += _realTimeSimulationTimerElapsed;
    _realTimeSimulationTimer.Enabled = true;
}

private void _realTimeSimulationTimerElapsed(object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{  
     if (!StreamReaderWl1.EndOfStream)
            {        
                 linewl1 = StreamReaderWl1.ReadLine();
                 linewl2 = StreamReaderWl2.ReadLine();

                  // ...  do something
            }   
}
```

I want to start my `timer` later than the strat of the `.txt file` and I want to read latest lines written from when I started the `timer`.

Is there a way to try to look at the latest written line and start `streaming` form there on?

Comment: You could 'remember' the current/last position and seek to it while reopening and read from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Position property to get and save the last position of the FileStream and the use Seek to start reading from that position, next time the timer fires off.
Here is some example you can adapt to your code

```
    static long position = 0;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var timer = new Timer(128);
        timer.Elapsed += Process;
        timer.AutoReset = false;
        timer.Start();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void Process(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {            
        using (var fs = new FileStream("input.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            fs.Seek(position, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using (var fr = new StreamReader(fs))
            {
                while (!fr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(fr.ReadLine());
                }
                position = fs.Position;
            }
        }

        (sender as Timer).Start();
    }
```

Comment: Why not keep the `FileStream` in memory between call? That would remember your `Stream.Position` for you. It would also save on the overhead of opening and closing the file handle.

Comment: @Aron You are right, you could do that. The answer is more oriented towards being able to Seek into the file at a specific position after you open it. Given the short interval, I agree the overhead of getting a file handle every time is not a good idea.

Comment: I am reading in between the lines here but it sounds like the OP wants an IObservable<string> that pushes a new line each time the other process writes...

Comment: @bbeda thank you, I managed to work my way through following your code sample. Before starting the actual timer, I set the `stream` positon to the current stream length `fileStream.Position = fileStream.Seek(fileStream.Length, SeekOrigin.Begin);` This basically allows my stream continue right from the position where the file was before starting the timer.